# Hello, i was wondering if this is an isopod or a springtail

Tags: species-identification

[image]

**I want to make a terrarium so i was in need for a springtail is this it or is this something else**

Comment: Springtails are generally about 5 mm (1/4 inch). Photo is too blurry for me to tell what that might be. Possibly a woodlouse.

Comment: I say the same, regular woodlice, 4 of, so, isopods.

Answer (score -1):

Those are isopods. Springtails are hexapods.

Some of them are superficially similar, such as *Podura aquatica*:

[image]